# Error: bad value for -march= switch

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, makefile, arm, embedded

I wrote a Makefile and I can't get it to work. I have an option which is supposed to select which processor to compile to. However, when I run `make` from the commandline it says:

```
tandex@tandex-P-6860FX:~/emulators/nintendo sdks/3DS SDK [HomeBrew]$ make
gcc -march=arm7tdmi -static -fexceptions -fnon-call-exceptions -fstack-check test.c -c
test.c:1:0: error: bad value (arm7tdmi) for -march= switch

make: *** [ALL] Error 1
```

But in the man pages for gcc, it states that arm7tdmi is a permissible value. Am I missing something?

Makefile:

```
#3DS Compilation Makefile (c) TanDex (TEQ)RunawayFreelancers
#
#Version 0.99 (Alpha) For *nix Devices
#
#Please Check Back Soon for 3rd SDK

#SELECT THE COMPILER TO USE! GCC RECOMMENDED!
#FOR SANITY SAKE, USE C FILES WITH GCC AND CPP FILES WITH G++
CC=gcc
#CC=g++

#OBJECTCOPY REFERENCE, DO NOT REMOVE
OBJC=objcopy
OBJREFS= -O Binary

#SELECT THE PROCESSOR TO TUNE IT TO. ARMV7 (Nintendo DS) or ARMV9(Nintendo DS
(Graphical Support))
#or ARM11 Core ARM1176JZ-S and ARM1176JZF-S (3DS Processor? Not Sure if Correct. Try
and see if they Work?)
#
#NOTE: DS GAMES REQUIRE BOTH A ARM7 AND ARM9 BINARY. RUN THIS TWICE (ONCE FOR EACH)
#
#UNCOMMENT FOR PROCESOR

PROCESSOR=arm7tdmi
#PROCESSOR=arm946e-s
#PROCESSOR=arm1176jz-s
#PROCESSOR=arm1176jzf-s

#FILES
#
#PLACE ALL OF THE FILES HERE, THAT ARE BEING COMPILED!
FILES=test.c

#SET BIN FILE NAME BASED ON PROCESSOR SELECTED
ifeq($(PROCESSOR),arm7tdmi)\
NAME=ARM7.BIN
ifeq($(PROCESSOR), arm946e-s)\
NAME=ARM9.BIN
ifeq($(PROCESSOR), arm1176jz-s)\
NAME=ARM11.BIN
ifeq($(PROCESSOR), arm1176jzf-s)\
NAME=ARM11.BIN

#CREATE OBJECTS
ifeq($(CC), gcc)\
OBJECTS=$(FILES:.c=.o)
ifeq($(CC), g++)\
OBJECTS=$(FILES:.cpp=.o)

#FLAGS! DO NOT CHANGE THESE!!!!!!!!!!! THAT MEANS YOU!!!!!
#
#FOR THOSE WHO WANT TO KNOW WHAT THESE DO, HERE THEY ARE:
#-mtune=$(PROCESSOR)        FORE THE COMPILER TO TUNE OUTPUT TO THE SPECIFIED
PROCESSOR
#-static            REQUIRED FOR CLEAN BINARY OUTPUT?? (NOT SURE WHAT THIS
DOES, BUT WAS SUGESTED ON A POST ON STACKOVERFLOW)
#-fexceptions           FORCE EXCEPTIONS
#-fnon-call-exceptions      FORCE EXCEPTIONS TO ONLY BE RETURNED BY THE SYSTEM
(MEMORY AND FPU INSTRUTIONS FOR EXAMPLE)
#-fstack-check          FORCE STACK CHECKING (DS / 3DS USE AWKWARD STACK
IMPLEMENTATION)
CFLAGS=-march=$(PROCESSOR) -static -fexceptions -fnon-call-exceptions -fstack-check

ALL:
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(FILES) -c
.c.o:
$(OBJC) $(OBJREFS) $(OBJECTS) $(NAME)
.cpp.o:
$(OBJC) $(OBJREFS) $(OBJECTS) $(NAME)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are probably not calling the right gcc. You seem to be calling the gcc installed in your system, rather than the one that comes with the 3DS SDK.

Comment: no, this is custom make file. the 3ds sdk is another project i am working on in conjunction with this. right now thats just a folder with a test.c file to test the make file

Comment: @AlexanderFrankland What makes you believe that your version of GCC, as shipped by your Linux distro, could possibly have support for ARM CPUs? I doubt is has support for anything else than x86.

Comment: `gcc -v 2>&1 | grep "Target"` will tell you the target that the compiler is built for.  As Nikos says, you likely need to locate/build a cross compiler package. Each of the CPU listed on this page: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Submodel-Options.html has it's own set of acceptable `-march` values.

Comment: my fault for not knowing. i'll look for a cross compiler.

Comment: @AlexanderFrankland: there's no fault here. This is not something that is inherently obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the problem is with `-march=arm7tdmi`.

I think the workaround is to avoid using `-march=arm7tdmi`; and use `-march=cpu-type`, where `cpu-type` is one of the ones listed at [3.17.4 ARM Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html) of the GCC manual.

Here's part of the page:

> -march=name
>
> This specifies the name of the target ARM architecture. GCC uses this name to determine what kind of instructions it can emit when
>   generating assembly code. This option can be used in conjunction with
>   or instead of the -mcpu= option. Permissible names are: ‘armv2’,
>   ‘armv2a’, ‘armv3’, ‘armv3m’, ‘armv4’, ‘armv4t’, ‘armv5’, ‘armv5t’,
>   ‘armv5e’, ‘armv5te’, ‘armv6’, ‘armv6j’, ‘armv6t2’, ‘armv6z’,
>   ‘armv6kz’, ‘armv6-m’, ‘armv7’, ‘armv7-a’, ‘armv7-r’, ‘armv7-m’,
>   ‘armv7e-m’, ‘armv7ve’, ‘armv8-a’, ‘armv8-a+crc’, ‘iwmmxt’, ‘iwmmxt2’,
>   ‘ep9312’.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the other answer is correct. He's using the system gcc, which targets Intel processors, rather than a cross compiling gcc that would target the ARM processor in a Nintendo 3DS.