# How to fix error: bad value (native) for -march= switch and -mtune= switch?

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors, makefile, cmake

I am compiling the library provided here: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/fastann/, but

```
bash-3.2$ PREFIX=/usr/local/ cmake . && make                                    
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
 -Wall -O2 -g3 -msse2 -march=native -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti
--- Prefix = /usr/local/
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/dir
[ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fastann.dir/dist_l2.cpp.o
/path/to/dir/dist_l2.cpp:1: error: bad value (native) for -march= switch
/path/to/dir/dist_l2.cpp:1: error: bad value (native) for -mtune= switch
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/fastann.dir/dist_l2.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/fastann.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
bash-3.2$
```

This is only the first step in the provided instruction, and I don't know where to look next. Can somebody tell me what exactly is this error, and how to fix it?

Comment: This happens with which version of `gcc`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: bad value for -march= switch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13794272).

Comment: @alk - GCC 4.1.x. You still experience it in the wild due to CentOS 5.

Answer (score 2):

> How to fix error: bad value (native) for -march= switch and -mtune= switch?

The problem is with `-march=nartive`. According to Ian Lance Taylor on [GCC's mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2007-08/msg00244.html) (Ian is one of the GCC devs):

> The problem is that the driver code is not working, and the bug is
>   that gcc doesn't handle that [`-march=native`] correctly. There is some code in gcc to
>   handle the driver code failing, and it works for `-mtune=native`, but
>   not for `-march=native`.
>
> The driver code is supposed to change the `-march=native` to be
>   `-march=XXX` for your CPU. The code is in
>   `gcc/config/i386/driver-i386.c`.

So the workaround is to avoid using `-march=native`; and use either (1) `-m32` or `-m64`, or (2) use `-march=cpu-type`, where `cpu-type` is one of the ones listed at [3.17.15 Intel 386 and AMD x86-64 Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html) of the GCC manual. The list is extensive, and it includes `pentium`, `pentium2`, `pentium3` and `pentium4`.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to using a version of `gcc` equal or larger then 4.2.

`gcc`'s version 4.2 introduced the `native` march.

---

Use

```
gcc --version
```

to get `gcc`'s version information.

Comment: He can't switch compilers on some platforms. For example, CentOS 5 uses `gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)`. The next worse case I am aware of is OpenBSD and GCC 4.2.1. OpenBSD is contemporary - but its compiler is frozen at GCC 4.2.1.